# typescript <S> <R>

Tags: typescript

Изучаю TS, наткнулся на такую конструкцию во vuex - `ActionObject<S, R>`

Правильно ли я понимаю, что S, что R, это просто generic types? Просто очень смущает, что для них в документации использовалось строго `<T>`. Или я могу использовать заглавную букву любую под это дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать любое слово.

Comment: какой-то уж очень лаконичный ответ. может быть, стоит что-нибудь добавить? ссылку на документацию или ещё что-нибудь в этом духе.

Comment: любое слово? то есть он не будет ругаться, что такого типа нет. Проще говоря, если типа нет, это автоматом generic type?

Comment: @PaulWall, ты что-то не то спрашиваешь.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, ну это так же, как сказать, что для имени переменной можно использовать любое слово. Как-то сложно привести подходящую ссылку на документацию.